# How to emulate a more precise floating point?

Tags: c, precision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extended Precision Floating Point Library C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156002/extended-precision-floating-point-library-c-c)

I am working with fractals at university and now double precision isn't enough. I was using long double but i need more precision.

Is there any lib which implements a bigger precision? Like 512 bits, 1024 bits, or 2048 bits?

The more, the better!

I don't really care about speed.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156002/extended-precision-floating-point-library-c-c

Comment: Yet would respectfully disagree with your disregard for speed. What if the selected library does not let you hand in the project in time? More to the point: would you display the same attitude in production environment?

Comment: I have more than a year to finish to project, and a cluster to run the program. Speed is good,but not mandatory, for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a library called  [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), check it out.

Comment: +1, beat me by a few seconds! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am already porting the application to gmp.